# Extract zipfiles and gzfiles from a zip folder

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I can extract a zip folder containing several compressed files inside it but I don't know how to extract the zip and gz files inside it without repeating the same procedure two times?

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os

rootPath = zipDataDirectory
rootPath2 = workingDirectory
pattern = '*.zip'
pattern2 = '*.gz'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)
```

I tried the following code that is not working

```
extensionZip = "*.zip"
extensionGz = "*.gz"

for item in os.listdir(workingDirectory):
    if item.endswith(extensionZip):
        zipfile.ZipFile(item).extractall

    else:
        gzip.GzipFile.extract(item)
```

Comment: Surely you do not believe the `*` is actually part of the file extensions?

Comment: print(os.listdir(zipDataDirectory)) gives me the .py and the .zip folder

Comment: And how many of its files end with `*.zip`?

Comment: I have one zip folder with one zip file inside it and 30 gz files

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: only one files end with *.zip